# Текстовой редактор: хранение и изменение текста

Tags: c++, строки, text, редактор-текста

Хочу написать свой текстовой редактор (в образовательных целях). Сразу столкнулся с такой проблемой как хранить редактируемый текст?

Если в одной переменной типа `string`, то будет уходить много времени на вставку символов. Если использовать `list<char>`, то обращение к произвольному символу будет сложной задачей, да и выделять память отдельно для каждого символа тоже не хорошо. `vector` - это считай почти тоже самое, что и `string`. Понимаю, что на небольших файл это не имеет особого значения. Можно также делить редактируемый текст на строки и работать с каждой по отдельности (как в [kilo](https://github.com/antirez/kilo)). Но тут будут проблемы с производительностью, если весь текст это одна большая строка. Хотелось бы найти универсальное решение.

Как реализована данная функция в других редакторах? Порылся в исходниках [vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/tree/master/src)'a, но так и не смог найти структур и функций, которые бы за это отвечали.

Буду благодарен как за объяснения возможных способов решения данной задачи, так и за ссылки на исходные коды других текстовых редакторов с указанием мест где можно найти способ решения этой задачи.

Comment: В редакторах обычно используется индексация [строка, колонка], а обращение к произвольному символу по его индексу в целом тексте требуется редко. Однако, бывают тексты с огромным количеством строк, тогда появляется та же проблема. В принципе, это довольно общая проблема организации такой структуры данных, в которой и нужный элемент можно получить по индексу достаточно быстро как в массиве, и делать вставки/удаления быстро как в списке. Решается деревьями.

Comment: Какой-то из старых редакторов хранил в ОЗУ текст разбитым на две части — до курсора и после него. Эти части были раскиданы по двум границам одного буфера и разделены большим куском условно пустого пространства. А перемещение курсора гоняло куски текста из одной половины в другую взад-вперёд. *Так оптимизировалась скорость вставки символов.*

Comment: @AlexanderZonov думал на счет структур `set` и `map` из c++. Они реализованы деревьями. Но если честно не очень понимаю как их тут применить. Если использовать `map<int, char>`, то после вставки символа придется обновлять индексы.

Comment: Насколько помню, когда-то (как реализовано сейчас не знаю) в редакторе [jove](https://opensource.com/article/17/1/jove-lightweight-alternative-vim) файл хранился просто в виде массива указателей на строки (каждая выделялась в куче и также представляла собой последовательный массив символов строки без завершающего `\n` (признак завершения последней строки `\n`-м хранился отдельно)). А вот, наверное, самая интересная часть, это оптимальная отрисовка изменений буфера на экране, минимизирующая количество его обновлений.

Comment: @pank, не уверен, что `map` это может в плане интерфейса. Чтобы искать строку по целочисленному индексу, узел дерева должен хранить количество конечных элементов. Тогда можно использовать метод половинного деления или Фибоначчи для поиска строки по индексу. Сложность логарифмическая. При вставке/удалении строки нужно пробежать до корня дерева с инкрементом/декрементом на каждом узле.

Comment: Касательно отрисовки. Предлагаю визуализировать текст не целиком, а вертикальной стопкой непересекающихся блоков, где каждый блок состоит из некоторого целого числа строк и визуализируется в свой bitmap. Тогда при модификации текста потребуется перерисовать не весь текст, а только один такой блок, да сместить при необходимости координаты вывода на экран всех нижележащих блоков (разумеется, без их перерисовки). // cc: @avp

Comment: Кстати, представление текущее (*редактируемой*) строки может отличаться от остальных. Например, она может состоять из списка сегментов текста (разумного размера). Вставка новых символов всегда производится в конец текущего сегмента. Также и удаление производится с конца текущего сегмента. Таким образом сдвигать остаток символов строки никогда не нужно. Если сегментов становится слишком много, то проводим реорганизацию (до 3-х (или 2-х, в зависимости от положения курсора в строке) сегментов).

Comment: @Arhad, а как bitmap связан с **текстовым редактором**? Наверное, для отрисовки в учебном варианте оптимально будет использовать [curses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses) (и не заморачиваться самому особенностями разных типов терминалов)

Comment: @avp спасибо за советы. Обязательно их все учту. Для отрисовки уже выбрал `SDL2`. Там есть `SDL_Texture` и `SDL_Surface`. Кстати насчет наиболее быстрого способа визуалиции текста хотел задать отдельный вопрос :)

Comment: @avp, текстовый редактор GUI-ный? **Если да**, то вместо прямой отрисовки текста в окно имеет смысл визуализировать его в bitmap-ы и отрисовывать в окне уже их. **Если нет**, то да, вы правы. **P. S.** Комментарием выше автор выбрал SDL. То есть редактор не консольный CUI-ный.

Comment: Нашёл [репоизторий](https://github.com/tim95bell/TextEditor) на github созданный 4 дня назад, в котором начата реализация редактора с использованием `C++, SDL, and OpenGL`. Но вроде пока что ничего особенного не написано. [Тут](https://github.com/psqq/kilo) если интересно (на скорую руку написанный) мой код sdl обертки для kilo.

Comment: @pank, а зачем вам SDL? Разве это не пушка для воробьёв? У вас же текстовый редактор, а не интерактивное мультимедийное приложение.

Comment: @Arhad хочется в деталях во всем разобраться вплоть до создания изображения с текстом, да и в будущем хотелось бы добавить дополнительные возможности. Например, просмотр дерева файлов, просмотр файлов изображений и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: `vector<string>` или `list<string>` - по строке текста в каждом элементе. Если есть необходимость бороться с длинными строками, то `list<list<string>>` - ограничить длину фрагмента строки. Опять же, выбрать между вектором и списком по необходимости.

Answer (score 3):

Есть следующая книга: Э.Гамма. Р. Хелм. Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования. Там как раз рассматривается пример проектирования редактора документов. Вам точно туда стоит заглянуть, найдете там много ответов.